# Script block error when using rename-item cmdlet

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Upon execution of the following code:

```
$n = 1
$array = "L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "L6", "L7", "L8", "L9"
ls *.pdf | sort lastwritetime | foreach-object {
if ($_.name.substring(0,2) -cnotin $array) {
ren -newname { "L$global:n " + $_.name -f $global:n++ }
} else {
$global:n++
}}
$n = 0
```

I encounter the following error:

> Rename-Item : Cannot evaluate parameter 'NewName' because its argument
> is specified as a script block and there is no input. A script block
> cannot be evaluated without input. At line:3 char:14
>
> - ren -newname { "L$global:n " + $_.name -f $global:n++ }
> - ```
>            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [Rename-Item], ParameterBindingException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptBlockArgumentNoInput,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Where am I going wrong? The pipeline has the name of a file which is in the current directory but still says it receives no input.

Comment: As the error states, you're not piping any input to `ren`. `$_ |ren -newname { ...}`

Comment: Isn't ""L$global:n " + $_.name -f $global:n++" an input? How can I fix it?

Comment: The array you use only has 9 items. What if `Get-ChildItem` (`ls`) finds more files? If `$n` reaches 10, it will also match `L1`...

Comment: It's not pipeline input. Fix it by adding `$_ |` just before `ren`, exactly as shown in my previous comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The pipeline has the name of a file which is in the current directory but still says it receives no input.

The *enclosing* pipeline does, but the nested pipeline (`ren -newname { ... }`) does not have any pipeline input because you never pipe anything to it.

Change to:

```
$n = 1
$array = "L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "L6", "L7", "L8", "L9"
ls *.pdf | sort lastwritetime | foreach-object {
  if ($_.name.substring(0,2) -cnotin $array) {
    $_ |ren -newname { "L{0}{1} " -f $global:n++,$_.name }
  } else {
    $global:n++
  }
}
$n = 0
```

By piping the existing item (`$_`) from the parent pipeline, we've know given `ren`/`Rename-Item` something to bind `$_` to in the nested pipeline

Beware that, as [Theo mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67176386/script-block-error-when-using-rename-item-cmdlet#comment118741655_67176386), if the target directory contains more than 9 files, your script might start having some potentially unexpected behaviors (although you haven't clearly stated what you're trying to achieve, so maybe that's what you want)